# Custom rest fields not loaded in rest api cpt response

Tags: php, plugin-development, custom-field, rest-api

I have a custom endpoint that will be used from my vue app to load custom post type I've registered using a custom plugin. I need to add some custom fields to the response when the posts are loaded and I've used this code

```php
    public function register_custom_endpoints() 
    {
        register_rest_route( 
            'rest/v1', 
            '/loadMessages', 
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'get_comunications' ), 
                /*'permissions_callback' => function(){
                    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                        return new WP_Error(
                            'rest_not_logged_in',
                            __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
                            array( 
                                'status' => 403 
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }*/
            )
        );
    }

    public function register_custom_fields()
    {
        register_rest_field( 
            array(
                'comunications',
                'academy'
            ), 
            'post_meta', 
            array(
                'get_callback' => array( $this, 'get_custom_post_meta' )
            ) 
        );
    }
```

And these are the callbacks

```php
    public function get_comunications( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        /*if( !wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Nonce' ) ), 'wp_rest' ) ){
            return new WP_Error(  
                'expired_or_invalid_nonce',
                __( 'Invalid nonce.' ),
                array(
                    'status' => 403
                )
            );
        }*/

        $q = new WP_Query( 
            array(
                'post_type' => 'comunications',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            ) 
        );
        return new WP_REST_Response( $q->posts, 200 ); 
    }

    public function get_custom_post_meta( $object )
    {
        $post_id = $object['id'];
        //return get_post_meta( $post_id );
        return $post_id;
    }
```

The posts at the moment don'y have any post meta but I expect to see the empty field into the response when posts are loaded. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: `register_rest_field` will only add it to the post in the core endpoints. If you have a custom endpoint it's only going to return what you return, and you're just returning the `posts` property of `WP_Query`, and those will never include meta.

Comment: so what's the way to return also the custom field?

Comment: You need to return it in your `get_comunications()` callback. So you'd need to loop over each post and prepare it for response by adding the custom field.

Comment: Not sure to understand, why I need to use `register_rest_field` function if I need to add manually the post meta into the api response callback?

Comment: You don't. As I said, that's for adding it to core endpoints. You should probably just be using core endpoints anyway, because your custom endpoint isn't doing anything the core endpoints can't do.

Comment: I've removed the core endpoints from rest routes, can be this the cause?

Comment: No. You're not listening to what I'm saying. `register_rest_field` only adds the field to the core endpoints. It's never going to add them to your custom route, regardless of whether or not the core endpoints have been removed.

Comment: can you show an example to be more clear?So I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with a simple solution. after the query to the DB to get all the desired CPT I'm looping the posts object and inside my loop I get the postmeta I will need to add and append them to each post before return the data to the front-end

```php
    public function get_contents( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        if( !wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( $request->get_header( 'X-WP-Nonce' ) ), 'wp_rest' ) ){
            return new WP_Error(  
                'expired_or_invalid_nonce',
                __( 'Nonce expired or invalid.' ),
                array(
                    'status' => 403
                )
            );
        }
        $post_type = sanitize_text_field( $request->get_param( 'post_type' ) );

        $q = new WP_Query( 
            array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            ) 
        );
        
        $posts = array();
        //
        foreach( $q->posts as $p ){
            $post_meta = get_post_meta( $p->ID );
            if( $post_meta ){
                $p->post_meta = $post_meta;
            }
            array_push( $posts, $p );
        }
        //
        return new WP_REST_Response( $posts, 200 ); 
    }
```